# Intellij IDEA 14 - Show intention actions (ALT+ Return)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

1. Call unimplemented method, it is highlighted red.
2. Place caret at this method and press ALT+Return.
3. Choose create method 'methodNameHere'.
4. Method body is created right underneath the invocation line of this method.

**Question:** How can I set IDEA to create this methods/variables etc. in the end of the class?